# How do I delete a paused book from iBooks on iPad?

Tags: ipad, books

While fishing for free books, I tapped purchase for a book which is larger than 500mb. I've noticed the size only after buying. I paused the download by tapping on the book.

Now I was not able to delete it from iBooks. Is there a way to delete the book from iBooks app? I could download from iCloud anytime. I don't want the book to be display in my iBooks shelf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your iPad to the computer and let it sync (if necessary). You can then select the book and delete it.